# assign value to select in methods in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```html
<a-radio-group
  @change="changeName"
  v-decorator="[
                'name',
                { initialValue: 'light' },
                ]"
>
  <a-radio value="iphone">Iphone</a-radio>
  <a-radio value="samsung">Samsung</a-radio>
</a-radio-group>
   

<a-form-item label="Value" :colon="false">
  <a-select placeholder="Select a value">
    <a-select-option></a-select-option>
  </a-select>
</a-form-item>
```

```
methods: {
  changeName(event) {
    var value = event.target.value;
    if (value == 'iphone') {
      // I want to assign the select-option the value : 
      //<a-select-option value="ip12">Iphone 12</a-select-option>
      // <a-select-option value="ip13">Iphone 13</a-select-option>
    } else {
      //<a-select-option value="ss10">Samsung note 10</a-select-option>
      // <a-select-option value="ss9">Samsung note 9</a-select-option>
    }
  }
}
```

How do I change the `<a-select-option>`s when I select a radio button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compute the `<a-select>`'s options based on the `<a-radio-group>`'s value.

1. Instead of the `change`-event handler, use a [`v-model` directive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-model) on the `<a-radio-group>` to store the selected brand, and on the `<a-select>` to store the selected phone:

   ```html
   <template>
     <a-radio-group v-model="selectedBrand">
       <!-- brands -->
     </a-radio-group>

     <a-select placeholder="Select a value" v-model="selectedPhone">
       <!-- phone options -->
     </a-select>
   </template>

   <script>
   export default {
     data () {
       return {
         selectedBrand: '',
         selectedPhone: '',
       }
     }
   }
   </script>
   ```
2. Add a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties) for the options to show based on the selected brand:

   ```js
   const PHONE_OPTIONS = {
     iphone: [
       { value: 'iph12', label: 'Iphone 12' },
       { value: 'iph13', label: 'Iphone 13' },
     ],
     samsung: [
       { value: 'ss10', label: 'Samsung Note 10' },
       { value: 'ss9', label: 'Samsung Note 9' },
     ],
   }

   export default {
     computed: {
       phoneOptions() {
         return PHONE_OPTIONS[this.selectedBrand]
       },
     },
   }
   ```
3. Use a [watcher](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) on the phone options to automatically select the first one.

   ```js
   export default {
     watch: {
       phoneOptions(value) {
         this.selectedPhone = value?.[0].value
       },
     },
   }
   ```
4. Render the phone options:

   ```html
   <a-select-option v-for="opt in phoneOptions" :key="opt.value" :value="opt.value">
     {{ opt.label }}
   </a-select-option>
   ```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue2-interdependent-options?file=src/App.vue)

Comment: Thank you. That's great. This is the answer I was looking for. It helped with my work